# String from input tag on JSP work don't correct in SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

i have some trouble when trying to search some data in my data base.
I have input tag where i write some text, then it from JSP gets to controller, service, and in dao i have a query where put this String into the query, when this String is in English - all works fine, but when i write String in Ukrainian searching don't work. Can someone help ?

JSP page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form"  
uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Головна сторінка</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url   
value="../../resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>"   
rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<c:url var="addUrl" value="/main/mainFrame/new"/>
<c:url var="searchResult" value="/main/resultOfSearching"/>



<a href="${addUrl}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn- 
lg btn-block" style="margin-left:auto;

margin-right:auto;

width:250px;

margin-top:50px;">Додати звернення</button></a>


<form:form method="GET" action="${searchResult}"     
modelAttribute="ListOfAppeals">

<div class="col-lg-6" style="width:800px;
                         margin-left:270px;
                         margin-top:200px;">

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" formenctype="text/plain" name="searchChar"   
class="form-control" placeholder="Введіть ідентифікатор для пошуку">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Пошук</button></a>
  </span>
</div>

</div>

</form:form>

 </body>

</html>
```

searchingResult JSP page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="styles/searchingResultPage.css" />" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url   
value="../../resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" 
rel="stylesheet">
<title>Результати пошуку</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center">Список звернень (запитів)</h1>


<table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 1200px;margin-right: 
auto;margin-left: auto">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center">#</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Номер звернення (запиту)</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Вхідний номер</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">П.І.Б. народного депутата</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Резолюція керівника</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Тип документу</th>
    <th class="example" style="text-align:center">Дії з 
документом</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${ListOfAppeals}" var="Appeals">

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out value="${Appeals.id}"/>   
</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out  
value="${Appeals.number}"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out 
value="${Appeals.incomingDate}"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out   
value="${Appeals.nameOfDepute}"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out 
value="${Appeals.resolutionOfChief}"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><c:out 
value="${Appeals.typeOfAppeal}"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="btn   
btn-danger btn-sm">видалити</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"  
style="margin-left: 5px;">редагувати</button></td>
    </tr>

</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resultOfSearching", method =  
RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSearchResult(Model model,     
@ModelAttribute("searchChar")String searchResult)  {
    List<DeputesAppeal> deputesAppeals =  
deputesAppealService.abstractSearch(searchResult);
    model.addAttribute("ListOfAppeals", deputesAppeals);
    return "searchingResultPage";
}
```

Service method

```
public List<DeputesAppeal> abstractSearch(String searchingChar) {
    return deputesAppealDao.abstractSearch(searchingChar);
}
```

and DaoLayer

```
public List<DeputesAppeal> abstractSearch(String searchingChar) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from   
DeputesAppeal where concat(NumberOfAppeal, DateOfIncomingAppeal,  
NameOfDepute, ResolutionOfChief, TypeOfAppeal)  like '%" + 
searchingChar + "%'");
    return query.list();
}
```

when sql logs

```
  from DEPUTES_APPEAL deputesapp0_ where concat(NumberOfAppeal,    
    DateOfIncomingAppeal, deputesapp0_.NameOfDepute,  
    deputesapp0_.ResolutionOfChief, TypeOfAppeal) like '%[B@7c815681%'
```

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: where ? i am work on ubuntu

Comment: I had a problem with Russian language due to improper encoding - I set UTF encoding in MySQL (you can read this manual http://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/), during connection to database (something like this jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8) and also added Filter for application in WebInitializer (you can see example here https://github.com/lenach87/Ochumailoc/blob/master/src/main/java/mailoc/config/WebInitializer.java). Hope this would be helpful to you

Comment: this word doesn't have any bind with data base

Comment: `formenctype="text/plain"` might be the culprit. Also you should not use string concatenation to build query

Comment: please debug and see which type is passed to getSearchResult method, because i see 'like '%[B@7c815681%'' in your log means that was passed as an object other than string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Character encoding filter like this (in your web.xml file):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

and put this filter the first filter in your web.xml

Comment: i have this filter, what do you mean under "And also replace UTF-8 with your desired character encoding"

Comment: I didn't know which character encoding must be used for your language

Comment: Did you define mapping for UTF-8 filter?
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>